# Problem with making slide show effect with img tags created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I assume that for loop can iterate nodelist objects so I don't know why it doesn't work properly. I want to iterate through for loop nodelist of 3 img tags created dynamically. First among them does not have a displayNone class and other img tags do have it. Loop should check in every iteration if element (img tag) has NOT that class and if not to add that class to that particular element and to remove that class from next if next isn't last element of the list. In that case, class should be removed from last element and added to first. Why this code does not solve that issue? This is the error that is on display at console panel: main.js:101 Uncaught TypeError: images[i].not is not a function
at slideShow (main.js:101)
at :1:1

```
function slideShow(){
    var images = $("#slider img");
    for (var i=0;i<images.length;i++){
        if(i!=images.length-1){
            if(images[i].not(".displayNone")){
                images[i].addClass("displayNone");
                images[i+1].removeClass("displayNone");
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
            images[i].addClass("displayNone");
            images[0].removeClass("displayNone");
        }
    }
    setTimeout("slideShow()",3000);
}
slideShow();
```

Comment: use `$(images[i])` as jquery object if you are applying jquery methods on them.

Comment: Your setTimeout should be: `setTimeout(slideShow, 3000);` Also take a look at [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) and you can avoid the recursion.

Comment: That `if()` is not valid. `not()` does not return a boolean. Use `hasClass()` instead

Comment: @ikiK THANKS A LOT. That was solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put `images[i]` into `$()` = `$(images[i])`

**Using Pure JavaScript:**

Use `element.classList` `.contains` method:

`element.classList.contains(class);`

```
 function slideShow(){
        var images = $("#slider img");
        for (var i=0;i<images.length;i++){
            if(i!=images.length-1){
                if(!images[i].classList.contains(".displayNone")){ 
                    images[i].classList.add("displayNone");
                    images[i+1].classList.remove("displayNone");
                    break;
                }
            }
            else {
                images[i].classList.add("displayNone");
                images[0].classList.remove("displayNone");
            }
        }
        setTimeout("slideShow()",3000);
    }
    slideShow();
```

**Using jQuery:**

```
function slideShow(){
        var images = $("#slider img");
        for (var i=0;i<images.length;i++){
            if(i!=images.length-1){
                if(images[i].not(".displayNone")){ 
                    $(images[i]).addClass("displayNone");
                    $(images[i+1]).removeClass("displayNone");
                    break;
                }
            }
            else {
                $(images[i]).classList.add("displayNone");
                $(images[0]).classList.remove("displayNone");
            }
        }
        setTimeout("slideShow()",3000);
    }
    slideShow();
```

Comment: I changed that part but initial image is still not changing and this error is showing in console Uncaught TypeError: images[i].addClass is not a function

Comment: This will not work if you are using jQuery, you need put then into `$(images[i])`